# Enable Kernel Debuggin in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: debugging, windbg, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to enable kernel debugging in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (running in Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 R2):

```
bcdedit /dbgsettings 1394 channel:32 
bcdedit /debug ON
shutdown /r /f /t 0
```

But when I run in WinDbg:

> File -> Kernel Debug -> Local -> Ok

I see message box:

```
--------------------------- WinDbg:6.12.0002.633 AMD64 
--------------------------- The system does not support local kernel debugging.

Local kernel debugging requires Windows XP, Administrative
privileges, and is not supported by WOW64.
Only a single local kernel debugging session can run at a time.
Local kernel debugging is disabled by default in Windows Vista, you must run 'bcdedit -debug on' and reboot to enable it.
--------------------------- OK ---------------------------
```

bcdedit's output:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {22afa782-ce1f-11e2-824a-de42722e0fff
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {22afa784-ce1f-11e2-824a-de42722e0fff
recoveryenabled         Yes
testsigning             Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {22afa782-ce1f-11e2-824a-de42722e0fff
nx                      OptOut
debug                   Yes
```

Comment: On Windows 7 I was able to get local kernel debugging to work by running "bcdedit -debug on" and then rebooting the machine.  I am using x64 version of Windows and it only works when using WinDbg (x64).

Answer (score 0):

As the statement says, this only works on Windows XP.
For local kernel debugging I always use [SysInternals LiveKd](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To debug local kernel, you have to give this command and Reboot.

```
bcdedit -debug on
```

After Restart, **open checked build environment** **NOT free build** and launch windbg.

Comment: what is "open checked build environment NOT free build" ?

Comment: IMHO the daily Windows builds we use are all free build. Checked builds are non-optimized by the compiler and they can be used together with private tokens in private PDBs, which are not generally available to us.

Answer (score -1):

basically you can`t debug kernel locally. You need two separate computers (or vm guest + host) to debug.

Comment: If it was impossible such a thing as "Local" tab in "Kernel Debugging" would not exist :)

Comment: On Windows Server 2012 I had success: Kernel Debugging -> Local + .server tcp:port

Comment: This isn`t classical debugging, you can only look into km memory and read values:

"Typically, you cannot use any command that causes the target computer to stop, even momentarily, because you cannot resume operation." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553382(v=vs.85).aspx